# Powers of 10 not working correctly in Python: multiplying by 10**7 not returning the same as 10e7

Tags: python, exponent

I thought the syntax 10e7 is equivalent to 10**7.

However, I get the following odd output that I do not understand.

```
-8.555376292852173*(10**7)
```

returns

```
-85553762.92852174
```

And

```
-8.555376292852173*(10e7)
```

returns

```
-855537629.2852174
```

The output of the first is a factor 10 smaller than the output of the second. I am using Jupyter lab.

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `10**7` is indeed `10^7` but `10e7` is actually equal to `10*10^7`. `1e7` is already `10^7`.

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake. You need `1e7`, not `10e7`. `10e7` is off by a factor of 10.